# I'm working on windows form with access database. i want to get the count of product between two dates. This following query is getting error

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
select DOA, count(srno) 
from purchase 
where pname='" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' 
AND company='" + cmb_cmp.Text + "' AND DOA between '" + date + "' and '" + dat + "';
```

Comment: What error? How do you call it?

Comment: Please do not try to fix the error but instead look up parameterized queries and switch to using that. String concatenation for constructing sql is a bad practice - susceptible for sql injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you read up on parameters:

```
AND company='" + cmb_cmp.Text + "' AND DOA between #" + date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# and #" + dat.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```